# Unable to get Object out of Function

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, facebook-graph-api, var

I am working on an awesome project, normally i use AS3 but now I am using Javascript.

I have the following information: below I am trying to access the detect line, basically what i need is detect(response.username). I have tried a lot of things, can anyone help?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){


    var appId = "121070974711874";
    // If logging in as a Facebook canvas application use this URL.
    var redirectUrl = "http://apps.facebook.com/bggressive";
    // If logging in as a website do this. Be sure to add the host to your application's App Domain list. 
    var redirectUrl = window.location.href;




    // If the user did not grant the app authorization go ahead and
    // tell them that. Stop code execution.
    if (0 <= window.location.href.indexOf ("error_reason"))
    {
        $(document.body).append ("<p>Authorization denied!</p>");
        return;
    }


    // When the Facebook SDK script has finished loading init the
    // SDK and then get the login status of the user. The status is
    // reported in the handler.
    window.fbAsyncInit = function(){


        FB.init({
            appId : appId,
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            oauth : true
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus (onCheckLoginStatus);
    };



    (function(d)
    {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));



    function onCheckLoginStatus (response)
    {
        if (response.status != "connected")
        {
            top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent (redirectUrl) + "&scope=user_photos,friends_photos";
        }
        else
        {$
            // Start the application (this is just demo code)!
            $(document.body).append ;

            FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) {
                function detect(URL) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = URL;
                    image.onload = function() {
                        var result = 'result'; // An example result

                    }

                    document.body.appendChild(image)

                }
                detect("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200");








            });



            FB.api('/me/friends?fields=id,first_name', function(response) {
                var randomFriend = Math.floor(getRandom(0, response.data.length));
                gFriendID = response.data[randomFriend].id;
                var randomFriend = Math.floor(getRandom(0, response.data.length));
                gFriendID2 = response.data[randomFriend].id;



                function friend1(URL) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = URL;
                    image.onload = function() {
                        var result = 'result'; // An example result

                    }

                    document.body.appendChild(image)

                }
                friend1("https://graph.facebook.com/" + gFriendID + "/picture?width=200&height=200");


                function friend2(URL) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = URL;
                    image.onload = function() {
                        var result = 'result'; // An example result

                    }

                    document.body.appendChild(image)

                }
                friend2("https://graph.facebook.com/" + gFriendID2 + "/picture?width=200&height=200");


            });





        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display the image of the currently logged in user, and then `detect` when the image has loaded. You are trying to fix this part of the code:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) {
    function detect(URL) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL;
        image.onload = function() {
            var result = 'result'; // An example result

        }

        document.body.appendChild(image)

    }
    detect("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200");
});
```

There's a number of things going on here. First, all the information you need to know which image to load will be supplied to you from the `/me/` call. The only thing you have to pass to the function is a callback (what to do when the image loads), and possibly the width and height.

Second, if you set the `src` property of your image, the image will be loaded. If you set the `onload` handler after the `src` property, and the image is fetched from the cache, the image will already have finished loading, the `onload` event will already have fired, and the handler won't be called. This is explained a lot better in [this post](http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html).

So, you could do it like this:

```
function detect(username) {
    var result = 'result'; // An example result
}

function displayPicture(width, height, callback) {
    FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) { 
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            callback(response.username);
        };
        image.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
        document.body.appendChild(image);
    });
}

displayPicture(200, 200, detect);
// or
displayPicture(200, 200, function(username) {
    var result = 'result'; // An example result
));
```

Well, good luck! I hope this was, in fact, what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hi, no that is a part of the code, which is working fine, i now need to have username which basically the same ass the line "detect()"but is stead of 

    detect("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200");

i need

detect(response.username);


that i can load outside this code in a new function or VAR

Comment: Ok, right. In your code, the `detect()` function loads an url into an image. What would you like this other detect function to do? I suppose it shouldn't load `response.username` into the `src` field of an image object?

Comment: i just need to have the response.username to load so i can use that to pass on to another function outside this this code

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "to load". It would seem that you already loaded response.username when you used it in constructing the picture url. You got it from the `/me/` call. You can pass it to another function (say, `aFunction()`), by calling `aFunction(response.username);` in the line below `detect("https://(...)");`. Will that work?

Comment: I need to pass the detect(response.username) to a function outside the function were I load it from Facebook.

Comment: However ill try to use partially your code many thanks for your reply :),  ill come back on this later

Comment: Hi @Spiny Norman the normal code you provided did not work ... :(, the thing is i just need to pass the username no picture is required. i just want to pass the username

Comment: at the moment i have the following code
    FB.api('/me', function PasOn(response) 
        {GetID = response.username
     return GetID})


    function returndata(){
     get = PasOn
        return get